# Python Package always installing in develop mode

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python command line tool that I am trying to package. Below is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='schema-tool',
    author='Me',
    description='A schema tool to manage alters and migrations.',
    version='1.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['schema=src.schema:main'],
    }
)
```

And here is my setup.cfg:

```
[bdist_rpm]
release=1
doc_files=
    README.txt
    LICENSE.txt
    PKG-INFO
    doc/
requires=python
build_requires=python
```

When I run `python setup.py install`, it does create the `site-packages` dir but a `dist/`and `.egg-info` directories get created locally (the library / where I am calling setup.py). In the `site-packages`, it also creates a `.egg-link` file that links back to my local directory (the actual library).

This looks like the develop behaviour. Is there something wrong I am doing that setup.py thinks this is develop mode? I'd like to do a full installation regardless of my library directory. I've also tried installing it using pip and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `develop` install with `pip uninstall X` and try reinstalling?  You can also try bumping the version number.  Pip does some checking w/ versions and may or may not actually install the package.

Comment: @mtik00 Yes I did. And I did try to bump the version, same issue.

Comment: What happens if you build the package to a wheel and then install the wheel instead of using setup.py directly?